# php unable to display image

Tags: php, image

images are exist in my server but i am unable to find or display image with the help of following code

```
$myimages='/uk/images/7.jpg';
echo $myimages;
echo '<img src="'; echo $myimage; echo '">';

if (file_exists($myimages)) {
    echo "The file $myimages exists";
}
else {
    echo "The file $myimages does not exist";
    $myimages=$info['aw_image_url'];
    echo $myimages;
}
```

The code always returns `The file doesn't exist` nor does it display the image.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: path tested its ok.....

Comment: Your variable is `$myimages` but you are outputting `$myimage`.

Comment: Simplify this with one statement instead of three:  `echo '<img src="' . $myimages . '" />';` or better still, `echo "<img src='$myimages' />";`

Comment: Or better still `?><img src="<?= $myimages; ?>" /><?php`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is correct for your browser, but not for `file_exists`. It checks path relative to your filesystem, so if you start the path with `/`, it will check starting from the root of your filesystem

Also, variable name where you're outputing image is `$myimages`, not `$myimage`

Comment: thanks...the variable name was wrong. woundering how to check file exists or not....i tried everyting no luck...

Comment: you need correct filesystem path, check what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives, and append the rest of the path

Answer (score 0):

1) You use a different variable to output the image tag, so the image tag is broken

2) `file_exists` looks at absolute path of the server, so it's not looking it from the "webroot" perspective that the image tag looks from

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$myimages="uk/images/7.jpg";
 echo $myimages;
 echo "<img src='$myimages' />";



if (file_exists($myimages)) {
    echo "The file $myimages exists";
} else {
echo "The file $myimages does not exist";
$myimages=$info['aw_image_url'];
echo $myimages;
}
```

Comment: forgot some `.` concats in that img `echo` or perhaps you meant to escape the inner quotes or use single

Comment: lol you still got it wrong, i fixed it

Answer (score -3):

You need to close the image tag with `/`

`$myimages='/uk/images/7.jpg';
 echo $myimages;
 echo '<img src="'; echo $myimages; echo '"/>';`

Note you are also missing the letter "s" in the `$myimages` variable on line three

Comment: that's good practice but not why the image wouldn't show

Comment: Oh really? Try to to display an image with the path stored in some other variable and see how far it gets you.

Comment: you don't need to close image tag in html5

Comment: umm, i posted my comment before you made your note about wrong variable. I was speaking at your original post which only said he should have that `/` at the end